# Why strpos + strlen is not secure in PHP (ex: exact matching)

Tags: php, strpos, strlen

I had a discussion with my teacher about the `mb_` functions. Whatever, one thing leading to another, we changed the subject and he gave me an example where `strpos` and `strlen` could be problematic, according to him:

```
$input  = "something"; # input given by the user
$string = "hello";     # string to match

if ( strpos($input, $string) !== false && strlen($input) < strlen($string) ) {
    echo "Correct input";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect input";
}
```

(The question is not about how to match 2 strings)

According to my teacher, there may be a way to validate the statement and execute the code `echo "Correct input";`.

However, I can't see a flaw in this. Maybe there could be a problem with encoding? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 !== compares value *and* type. That's valid syntax.

Comment: What are you *expecting* this code to check for?

Comment: Yeah, what are you asking? The first condition is false so it wouldn't even matter about the second.

Comment: My question wasn't well fomuled, I corrected this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

okey i think that the flaw will be the if statement logic

how will you use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function which check the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string , and in the same time you want to check if the input is greater than the subject ?

by logic it is impossible

Comment: Indeed it seems impossible, however, according to my teacher there is a way. I asked him but he didn't want to tell me, even after a few days of thinking. I recognize that my question wasn't well formuled.

Comment: does the $input and $string in your example are correct ? or they are such examples ?